# ¿Cómo reducir el código de una función hecha en python que convierte números arábigos a romanos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hice un código en python que, a través de una lista que contiene los elementos del output, convierte números comunes a romanos del 1 al 100. El código funciona correctamente, pero quería conocer como podría reducirse usando los elementos de la lista de manera eficiente, es decir, sin poner todos los número romanos en orden, ya que pienso ampliar del 1 al 1000 y el código se me hace muy extenso. Mi función luce de esta forma:

```
def numarom (arabigo):

romanos = [0,"I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X","XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "XC", "C"]

if arabigo < 11:
    return romanos [arabigo]
elif arabigo >10 and arabigo <20:
    return romanos [10] + romanos [arabigo-10]

elif arabigo == 20:
    return romanos [11]

elif arabigo >20 and arabigo <30:
    return romanos [11] + romanos [arabigo-20]

elif arabigo == 30:
    return romanos [12]

elif arabigo >30 and arabigo <40:
    return romanos [12] + romanos [arabigo-30]

elif arabigo ==40:
    return romanos [13]

elif arabigo >40 and arabigo <50:
    return romanos [13] + romanos [arabigo-40]

elif arabigo ==50:
    return romanos [14]

elif arabigo >50 and arabigo <60:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [arabigo-50]
    
elif arabigo ==60:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [10]

elif arabigo >60 and arabigo <70:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [10] +romanos [arabigo-60]

elif arabigo ==70:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [11]

elif arabigo >70 and arabigo <80:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [11] +romanos [arabigo-70]

elif arabigo ==80:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [12]

elif arabigo >80 and arabigo <90:
    return romanos [14] + romanos [12] +romanos [arabigo-80]

elif arabigo ==90:
    return romanos [15]

elif arabigo >90 and arabigo <100:
    return romanos [15] + romanos [arabigo-90]

elif arabigo ==100:
    return romanos [16]

else:
    return "fuera de rango"
```

Muchas gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Usamos un diccionario indexado por letra romana, cuyo valor es el valor de esa letra en enteros.

La función recibe un valor entero; lo divide sucesivamente por cada valor del diccionario, calculando asi cuantas veces es necesario repetir cada letra:

```
factores = dict(M=1000, D=500, C=100, L=50, X=10, V=5, I=1)

def int2roman(valor):
    roman = ""
    for letra, factor in factores.items():
        num = valor // factor
        if num:
            roman += letra * num
            valor %= factor
    return roman
```

Observación: produce valores en romano clásico, donde el orden de los elementos no altera el producto. O sea, IV y VI ambos valen lo mismo = 6.

**Comprobación**

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i, int2roman(i))
```

produce

```
1 I
2 II
3 III
4 IIII
5 V
6 VI
7 VII
8 VIII
9 VIIII
10 X
11 XI
12 XII
13 XIII
14 XIIII
15 XV
16 XVI
17 XVII
18 XVIII
19 XVIIII
20 XX
21 XXI
22 XXII
23 XXIII
24 XXIIII
25 XXV
26 XXVI
27 XXVII
28 XXVIII
29 XXVIIII
30 XXX
31 XXXI
32 XXXII
33 XXXIII
34 XXXIIII
35 XXXV
36 XXXVI
37 XXXVII
38 XXXVIII
39 XXXVIIII
40 XXXX
41 XXXXI
42 XXXXII
43 XXXXIII
44 XXXXIIII
45 XXXXV
46 XXXXVI
47 XXXXVII
48 XXXXVIII
49 XXXXVIIII
50 L
51 LI
52 LII
53 LIII
54 LIIII
55 LV
56 LVI
57 LVII
58 LVIII
59 LVIIII
60 LX
61 LXI
62 LXII
63 LXIII
64 LXIIII
65 LXV
66 LXVI
67 LXVII
68 LXVIII
69 LXVIIII
70 LXX
71 LXXI
72 LXXII
73 LXXIII
74 LXXIIII
75 LXXV
76 LXXVI
77 LXXVII
78 LXXVIII
79 LXXVIIII
80 LXXX
81 LXXXI
82 LXXXII
83 LXXXIII
84 LXXXIIII
85 LXXXV
86 LXXXVI
87 LXXXVII
88 LXXXVIII
89 LXXXVIIII
90 LXXXX
91 LXXXXI
92 LXXXXII
93 LXXXXIII
94 LXXXXIIII
95 LXXXXV
96 LXXXXVI
97 LXXXXVII
98 LXXXXVIII
99 LXXXXVIIII
100 C
```